# Get access to the Mac user account image

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimageview

I want to be able to set the user account image to an `NSImageView`, even if the image is a custom image.

Is this possible?

This is the image I am speaking of.

[image: Screenshot of Users & Groups pref pane]

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry. do i need to delete this question?

Comment: Nope. It'll just be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Collaboration Framework. CBIdentity to be exact.

```
-(NSImage *)userImage {
    CBIdentity *identity = [CBIdentity identityWithName:NSUserName() authority:[CBIdentityAuthority defaultIdentityAuthority]];
    return [identity image];
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/collaboration/cbidentity

Comment: Really this easy? Thanks a lot if this works!